# Automating sms sending by through Way2sms in Perl

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent, way2sms

I am trying to send sms through Way2sms using Perl LWP. The login part is being successful, after which I save the cookies to a local file. The welcome page after being logged in shows a **Send SMS** link, clicking on which one is redirected to another page with two inputs for mobile number and sms text and a button for submitting and sending the sms. Firebug reveals the page structure as shown in the figure. From the Iframe url and the form's `action` attribute, I constructed the form action's absolute URL and submit the form accordingly, with the cookie stored in the file. However, the sms isn't sent. What I am doing wrong here? The code is as follows. (The `name` attributes for the two text inputs are correct, taken by observing the source code in Firebug, although that's not included in the image)

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
open f, "> way2sms.txt";
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(
file => "cookies.txt",
autosave => 1,
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    agent =>
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
    cookie_jar => $cookie_jar,
);
my $response = $ua->post(
    'http://site2.way2sms.com/contentt/bar/Login1.action',
    {
        username => $user,
        password => $pass,
    }
);

if ( $response->is_redirect ) {
    $response = $ua->get( $response->header('Location') );
    print 5 if $response->decoded_content =~ /Kaustav Mukherjee/i; #prints it, showing that the login is successful
}   
my $smsresp = $ua->post("http://site5.way2sms.com/jsp/quicksms.action",[MobNo=>$mob,textArea=>'Hello World']);
```

[image]

Comment: A quick Google search revealed at least two scripts (one in Ruby, one in Python) that make use of Way2SMS from the command line. Are you sure you want to re-invent them?

Comment: I know the scripts you referred to. The Python script doesn't work. There is a similar Perl script too, in CPAN, but that has got an error in the makefile, so that doesn't install properly. I don't know Ruby, that's why I want to do it myself.

Comment: There is a limit of 100 sms per day through way2sms. So, if you were thinking it was unlimited, you were wrong.

Comment: I just whipped up a php script that works, for you: https://github.com/gprasanth/PHP-Way2SMS it works. But I don't know perl. Perhaps someone could port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WORKING** SCRIPT: *(Tested on 6/Sep/2012 3:00 PM GMT+5:30)*

```
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    use HTTP::Cookies;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent=>"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1");

    $ua->cookie_jar({ file => "/absolute/path/to/cookies.txt", autosave => 1 });
    # if windows, use \ instead of /

    # $ua->proxy(['http', 'ftp'], 'http://localhost:9666/');

    # below line seems to have done the trick
    push @{ $ua->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';

    my $response = $ua->post(
            'http://site5.way2sms.com/Login1.action',{
            "username" => "1234567890", # set your username
            "password" => "passwd0123", # set your password
            "userLogin" => "yes",
            "message" => "",
            "mobileNo" => "",
            }
    );

    if($response->is_success && $response->decoded_content =~ /Logout/i){ # you can have your name too in place of Logout
            print "Logged in!\r\n";
    }

    my $mob = "1234567890"; # mobile to send message to
    my $mes = "Hello! 123."; # message

    my $smsresp = $ua->post(
            "http://site5.way2sms.com/quicksms.action",
            {
                    'Action' => 'dsf45asvd5',
                    'HiddenAction' => 'instantsms',
                    'catnamedis' => 'Birthday',
                    'chkall' => 'on',
                    'MobNo' => $mob,
                    'textArea' => $mes,
            });

     if ($smsresp->is_success && $smsresp->decoded_content =~ /Submitted/i) {
         print "Sent!\r\n";
     }
```

P.S. I wish I could get that expired bounty O_o :)

Comment: Tough luck, I tried exactly the same thing, not working. Probably I am neglecting some of the CURL configurations.

Comment: can you set referer? you must set it to `http://site5.way2sms.com/jsp/InstantSMS.jsp`

Comment: @Cupidvogel EDITED My post see. you were making request to `/jsp/quicksms.action`
it should be just `/quicksms.action` please try now.

Comment: Yeah Perl provides an option to set the referer. I just did, still no result!

Comment: I edited my post while you were setting referer. You were making request to wrong url. Please try my code again.

Comment: No no, i didn't copy your earlier code. Your current code is the one I am trying (without the `jsp` bit in the URL), still no result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16300/discussion-between-goldenparrot-and-cupidvogel)

Comment: Nah, still not working! I mean, the login is okay, but the sms isn't being sent as usual. No issue with username and passwords, I have checked them 1000 times.

Comment: No problem, I am awarding you the bounty, just stick with me through this problem!

Comment: well it's working surely for me. may be someone else can confirm it too? something might be wrong with the number you are trying to send the message to? registered with [dnd](http://site5.way2sms.com/jsp/dnd.jsp) perhaps?

Comment: No, you take my number (9051457277. It's insecure to give my phone number in public, but I am too determined to sort this out!) and send me a sms through your script, let's see whether it comes to me!

Comment: sent. can we continue over chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16300/discussion-between-goldenparrot-and-cupidvogel

Answer (score 3):

I don't have your login info so that I can't test it for you.

but you can use some Firefox addon like TamperData or HttpFox to get which url is posted and what params are sent.

use Perl to make the same requests as browser and that will be good.

BTW, you can use one $ua to send two requests, no need to create another LWP::UserAgent instance.

Thanks

Comment: But for the 2nd request, I need to send the cookies already stored in the file from the first request, so shouldn't I be using a new `$ua`?

Comment: cookie will stay with that $ua from the first request. so that's fine.

Comment: But still the sms is not being sent. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to set up a new user agent, because you can simply reuse the previous one. AFAIK, the cookies will be in that user agent already.

Please note: the following is slightly OT.

I had a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMS::WAY2SMS

It installed fin on my pc. Maybe you want to try it again? Open a new question here with your concrete problem. Please feel free to notify me, so we may have a look at it.

Comment: That's the very one I tried to install, yet it failed. I will try again. In the meantime I will see whether using the same user-agent works.

Comment: I updated the code. Still it is not sending the sms. I studied the source code of the module you mentioned. Couldn't understand it much, plus he's using Mechanize. I guess it's acceptable to reinvent the wheel if you are trying a different approach!

Comment: Of course, TIMTOWTDI :) I have to admin, that it is difficult to analyse the problem without credentials. Can you post the html code you are getting, after the first request please?

Comment: I am getting the correct HTML, that of the welcome page, as evidenced by it containing my name.

Comment: Why don't you open an account by yourself? It will take 2 minutes, plus unlimited free sms as a bonus!

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to give my number to just some site I can't use anyway (I have no contacts in india). WWW::Mechanize has a way to dump what you are getting from a request. Your script can probably do it as well. I can only give you the hint to inspect exactly this page. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem. FYI, you can use Way2sms to send sms in your country too. It supports 160 countries.

Comment: Can anyone help me please? I am still stuck!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the Perl module Net::SMS::WAY2SMS for sending messages through way2sms.com?  It works great for me.

To install try:

```
C:\> perl -MCPAN -e "install Net::SMS::WAY2SMS"
```

Here is a code sample for sending SMS:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SMS::WAY2SMS;

my $sms = Net::SMS::WAY2SMS->new(
    'user' => 'user_name' ,
    'password' => 'secret_password',
    'mob' => ['1234567890', '0987654321']
);

# multi line sms
$sms->send(q[testing
sending
sms]);
```

Comment: Yeah I know (read the comments for the answer above). I am trying do it through `LWP`, this does it through `Mechanize`.

Comment: not working now gives following error

C:\Users\manish\Desktop>perl  test.pl
Error GETing http://wwwl.way2sms.com/jsp/InstantSMS.jsp?val=0: Not Found at lib/
Net/SMS/WAY2SMS.pm (autosplit into lib/auto/Net/SMS/WAY2SMS/send.al) line 113.

Answer (score 3):

Can't really see what's wrong but here are the things I'd start looking at:

- Check your real post request from the browser. Make sure javascript or something else isn't adding a variable not visible in the html.
- Tripple check that MobNo and textArea are really the only needed parameters. Often the submit button is checked for instance, to see what action was done.
- See what output you get when doing your post. Does it say something about a failure?
- Try to make the post directly from your browse (there are FF plugins for that) to make sure you're not busted on the lack of http-referrer

I've done a lot of scraping/pretending to be a browser and it's often very tedious. People add "security" checks. On common is that require you to post back a session variable for instance.

Good luck!

*edit: The site requires you to have a valid +91 number to register so I can't login and try for myself. Considering the amount of ads on that page do I really think they are adding some sort of variable since they live off ads and you're trying to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You are not including all the POST fields required

```
MobNo=
textArea=
HiddenAction=instantsms
login=
pass=
Action=
```

These all need to be included. There is [**this script**](http://www.goforexpert.com/php-curl-script-to-send-sms-from-way2sms/) in PHP that definitely works and you can refer to.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about Curl. Can you please elaborate what line 113-122 does?

Comment: It looks through the response of your login page, the one you have in `$response->decoded_content` and finds a match for the action string.

Comment: I did, there were some matches, but none regarding an `id` being assigned a value of `action`, they all dealt with classes named `action`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the value of the `value` clause for the element with `id` of **Action**?

Answer (score 0):

Well

1. Way2SMS.com is **changing the value** of hidden parameter '**catnamedis' monthly once**.
2. Way2SMS.com is **adding new hidden parameters** less frequently, like now they have added new parmeter called '**token**' which **varies depending on the user**, and the same with '**Action**' hidden parameter which also varies depending on the user.

So a script works for someone, does not works for other, because of this changing values, You have to **manually login into your way2sms.com account in a real browser and inspect element and find the value for Token and Action parameter for your account** (this value varies for every user).

Here is my **[Python Script](https://github.com/PrasannaVenkadesh/Py2SMS/blob/master/w2sms)** through which I am able to make it achieve.
You can use it as a reference for your Perl program

**Note:-** Before trying out my script, **change the value** of the **variable 'act'** in the script according to the **value of Action parameter** for your account, that you can find with the inspect element or Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53262539/3940406) using Python

To send `sms` using `way2sms` account, you may use below code snippet.

Before that you would be required to create an API `Key` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53262539/3940406)

```
import requests
url = "https://smsapi.engineeringtgr.com/send/"
params = dict(
    Mobile='login username',
    Password='login password',
    Key='generated from above sms api',
    Message='Your message Here',
    To='recipient')

resp = requests.get(url, params)
print(resp, resp.text)
```

**N.B: There is a limit of approx 20 sms per day**